# Wordpress pages hosted in heroku returns 404

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku, http-status-code-404

I have hosted my wordpress blog in heroku , everything works fine but intermittently I get 404 errors while accessing wordpress pages e.g. following return 404 (The requested URL /about/ was not found on this server.) most of the time

> http://pacific-wildwood-3863.herokuapp.com/about/

When I see the heroku log it has following

> Jul 16 21:40:06 pacific-wildwood-3863 app/web.1: [Wed Jul 17 04:40:05
>   2013] [error] [client 10.62.147.42] File does not exist:
>   /app/www/about, referer: http://pacific-wildwood-3863.herokuapp.com/
>   Jul 16 21:40:06 pacific-wildwood-3863 app/web.1: 10.62.147.42 - -
>   [17/Jul/2013:04:40:05 +0000] "GET /about/ HTTP/1.1" 404 204 Jul 16
>   21:40:08 pacific-wildwood-3863 heroku/router: at=info method=GET
>   path=/about/ host=pacific-wildwood-3863.herokuapp.com
>   fwd="182.72.242.3" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=3ms status=404
>   bytes=204

Not sure why it looks for about directory instead of being processed by wordpress. Is there any wordpress path configuration missing or I need to increase web dynos, currently I have only 1 ? Note that it works sometimes ?

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, quite a pain. Changing the permalinks works for a while, but your links are broken again once Heroku restarts dynos. I did the following to solve it:

1) Change your .htaccess file into:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

2) Make sure you save the .htaccess file encoded as ANSI (Look for "Western" + "Windows" when saving from TextEdit on Mac).

3) Commit changes and push to Heroku.

4) You can check whether it works by running `heroku restart`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Saved my day! But don't use TextEdit use TextWrangler or smth (western + windows on save)

Comment: This looks like it works! Many thanks. Would you be able to describe what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Going through [this forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/main-page-works-but-all-other-wp-pages-404-ing) it surprisingly worked when I checked the permalink option to another one. 
It also worked when I changed back, not sure what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you're not blocking the htaccess file in a git ignore. if you are, comment out the ignore then commit and push the htaccess file. That should fix your issue.

I use bedrock and had this same issue as it ignores the htaccess as default.

Hope that fixes it for you!